# Adding a row div after every four post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a `div class="row"` after every four posts in my wordpress website. The following code is used to generate the post types on my page:

```
<?php 
    $temp = $wp_query; 
    $wp_query = null; 
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
    $wp_query->query('showposts=8&post_type=branding'.'&paged='.$paged); 

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="featured-project-image">
        <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                the_post_thumbnail();
            }
             else { echo'<img src="';
                 echo get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); 
                 echo'/images/placeholder.jpg"/>'; } ?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: better [use another variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Standard_Loop) instead of `$wp_query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you want

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('showposts=8&post_type=branding' . '&paged=' . $paged);
?>
<div class="row">
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($wp_query->have_posts()):
    $wp_query->the_post();
    if ($i == 4) {
        $i = 0;
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php
    }
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="featured-project-image">
            <?php
            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {

                // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                the_post_thumbnail();
            } 
            else {
                echo '<img src="';
                echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
                echo '/images/placeholder.jpg"/>';
            } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    $i++;
endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Starting the `div` before the while loop ensures the first 4 are also contained in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Create variable, iterate it in each loop step and check if `% 4 == 0;`:

```
$i = 0;

while (...) {
    echo $i % 4 == 0 ? 'row' : ''; // echo .row in first step too. If you want in the 4th step, just change the result of modulo operator

    // your code here

    $i++;
}
```